# I can't get data from ArrayList in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Data1() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4}
        Dim Data2() As Integer = {4, 5, 6, 7, 1}
        Dim Data3 As New ArrayList
        Data3.Add(Data1)
        Data3.Add(Data2)
    End Sub

End Module
```

I would like get data into `Data3`

Comment: You haven't written any code to get data out of the ArrayList, only to put it in so far.

Comment: Are you trying to put `Data1` and `Data2` into `Data3` so that it is a flat list of integers?

Comment: Also, were you aware that `ArrayList` is obsolete? Use `List(Of Object)`.

Comment: what is your expected output in data3? is it 1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,1?

Comment: Thanks for comment.
i'm have data is array like continuous.
You have how to make

Comment: Dim Data3() As Integer = Data1.Concat(Data2).ToArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Data3.AddRange(Data1.Concat(Data2).ToArray())
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this method it slow because data has very.
I have picture about program : http://upic.me/i/y3/projcet.png

Comment: I don't think that there is any other way to do that process faster than this. Look i have updated my answer @user14602